# ServiceStack custom response on failed authentication

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack, restful-authentication

I've created a custom authentication for servicestack, which works well. The only problem is, that I get empty responses for every route, that requires authentication, when I am not logged in. How can I change this to return something like

```
{
    "statuscode":"401",
    "message":"Unauthorized"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Status Code and the Status Description is already in the returned HTTP Response Headers which is the expected response from a HTTP API. If you're calling from a web browser (i.e. client that accepts HTML) you can implement a `/login` page (configurable with `AuthFeature.HtmlRedirect`) to show the user a login page.

Otherwise you can override [OnFailedAuthentication()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/2e7cc585d401fe5b2f6ae3253f2f1c5660557ac5/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AuthProvider.cs#L309) in your Custom AuthProvider to override what gets returned in a failed Auth response, be mindful of what you write in the response body as a JSON response only makes sense for clients requesting JSON responses.